# Selecting the folder for performing specific operation on JPG files in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a function for tkinter GUI in python as below:

```
def mgpd():
answer = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,
                                 initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                 title="Please select a folder:")
if len(answer) > 2:
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in os.listdir(answer) if i.endswith(".jpg")]))
else:
    pass
t2.delete(0, 'end')
t2.insert('insert', 'task completed.')
```

Now when I select a folder the type error is given as `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. The problem is around `endswith` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is the answer:

```
def mgpd():
image_files = []
answer = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,
                                 initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                 title="Please select a folder:")
if len(answer) > 2:
    for file in os.listdir(answer):
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            image_files.append(os.path.join(answer, file))
        else:
            pass

outfile = os.path.join(answer, 'output.pdf')
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image_files)
file = open(outfile, "wb")
file.write(pdf_bytes)

t2.delete(0, 'end')
t2.insert('insert', 'task completed.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python complaining about bytes-like objects is usually because whatever string you're trying to alter is encoded. Instead of `if i.endswith(".jpg")]`, try `if i.decode().endswith(".jpg")]`.

Comment: Not successful it gives the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

Comment: I can't exactly simulate your code so it's harder to get an exact answer, however `i.endswith(b'.jpg')` or `from binascii import dehexlify` and `unhexlify(i).endswith(".jpg")]` could work.

Comment: maybe that is adding more a complexity, all I just want is to read all jpg files and pack it into a pdf. If the above code could be simplified or an alternative given is welcome.